# libmysql_.dll missing error in xampp

Tags: xampp

I have installed xampp into my windows 7 os (32 bit). I have made a test code in perl to check whether the xampp dbi works. But whenever I try running that program in localhost, I just get the following window.

[image: perl.exe - System Error - Window]

Help me solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download and install any perl setup ( eg: [strawberry perl](http://strawberryperl.com/) ). Search for the libmysql_.dll file in the newly installed perl environment. Copy it to *C:/xampp/perl/vendor/lib/auto/DBD/mysql*. [Note: Here c: is where the xampp has been installed.]